# Testing RecyclerView Adapters

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-espresso

I have a base `RecyclerViewAdapter` I want to test in isolation from my various child classes. How do I do this in isolation? I tried creating a slimmed down vanilla Activity in my test class, and using `ActivityTestRule` to launch it, but unfortunately the testing framework seems to want to launch activities that live in the actual app and not the test app. I don't want to resort to using Robolectric for this, since our team is committed to instrumentation testing using Espresso. What I really want to test is the behavior of the various `notify` methods in the adapter, since I'm seeing crashes around

> android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition

Comment: I think you will need to provide some code. In the current form it's too vague (at least for me).

Comment: See my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up resolving this by adding a dummy activity in the `debug` folder, then in my test code manually adding a `RecyclerView` to the Activity and then setting the adapter on it that I want to test in isolation. When the app compiles the manifest merger will merge any activities declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml` that live in the debug folder.

Here's my test setup code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapterTest {

    private MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<DummyActivity> activityTestRule =
        new ActivityTestRule<>(DummyActivity.class, true, false);

    @Rule
    public UiThreadTestRule uiThreadTestRule = new UiThreadTestRule();

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Throwable {
        final DummyActivity activity = activityTestRule.launchActivity(null);

        uiThreadTestRule.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(activity);
                recyclerView = new RecyclerView(activity);
                recyclerView.setId(R.id.recycler_view);
                activity.setContentView(recyclerView);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and declared the dummy Activity in `/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.DummyActivity" />
```

The dummy Activity is simply:

```
// Dummy Activity for testing
public class DummyActivity extends Activity {
}
```